# RecyclerView with Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-bitmap

I have a problem with recyclerview: when i move up and down in the list, the image of some rows are exchanged (or generally a few lines are set with images of other lines). I think that the problem is with the adpter but I can not understand what is wrong.

This in **myAdapter.java** :

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<myItem> myList;
    private Context context;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView photo;
        public TextView name;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowPhoto);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowName);
        }
    }


    public myAdapter(List<myItem> myList,Context context) {
       this.myList = myList;
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_custom, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myItem c = myList.get(position);

        if(c.getPathFoto()!=null){ 
            File f = new File(c.getPathPhoto());
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            holder.photo.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        holder.name.setText(c.getName());
    }



    public Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

}
```

All the images (that I use) have been previously saved in /data/data/myapp/app_data/imageDir (example /data/data/myapp/app_data/imageDir/21432342.png).

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: I suggest using Glide as library for loading images, is a lot simpler, and faster. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not clearing the image when it is null.

Try changing your OnBind method to this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    myItem c = myList.get(position);

    if(c.getPathFoto()!=null){ 
        File f = new File(c.getPathPhoto());
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        holder.photo.setImageBitmap(b);
    } else {
        holder.photo.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    holder.name.setText(c.getName());
}
```

Comment: You would be advised to now offload the image loading onto a separate thread as your performance will suffer if there are many items in your list.  Try Picasso.  http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try out third party library like Picasso or glide to make things simpler
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) 
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myItem c = myList.get(position);          
        Picasso.with(context)
               .resize(desiredWidth,desiredHeight)
               .load(new File(c.getPathPhoto())).into(holder.photo);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You surely have a concurrent problem. `RecyclerView` will re-use the view and call `onBindViewHolder` on it. Your method `onBindViewHolder` take time to load and set the bitmap.

**Easy (and dirty) solution:**
Add a `synchronized` on the method. This solution will not be very good for UI.

```
@Override
public synchronized void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    myItem c = myList.get(position);

    if(c.getPathFoto()!=null){ 
        File f = new File(c.getPathPhoto());
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        holder.photo.setImageBitmap(b);
    }

    holder.name.setText(c.getName());
}
```

**Good solution:**
You have to use an other thread for decoding your bitmap. And before calling `.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`, check if it's always the good bitmap. You can achieve that with setting the position in the holder for example.

Comment: the Kuff answer solve my specific (stupid) problem, but thanks for the suggestion to use another thread to decode the bitmap